# How to use a class variable?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class method `loadImage:(NSString *)path`to load image from path, if the path is nil, the load the default path image.

```
 +(NSImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)path{
   if(path== nil){
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"png"];
  }
}
```

because the default path is always using the same path, I want to calculate the path only once if I run the method 1000 times, like

```
if(defaultPath == nil){
    defaultPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"png"];
}
path = defaultPath;
```

, I think I can use static variable, but I don't know how to do it, please help me, I'm glad to know any suggestions about improving performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a static variable to hold the default path:

```
static NSString *defaultPath = …;
if (path == nil) {
   path = defaultPath;
}
```

But if you're doing it for performance reasons, first make sure it's worth it. Most probably it's a premature optimization that's not worth the trouble.

Comment: OP is specifically asking how to "calculate the path only once if I run the method 1000 times" -- that's a question on optimization, and doesn't sound premature.

Comment: I don’t think he’s really going to load a thousand images. Even if he does, what percentage of those calls is going to resolve the default image path? Even if the percentage is high enough, is the path lookup going to be an important number? I doubt that. You should always measure before doing this kind of optimization.

Comment: if I run `static NSString *defaultPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"png"]` 100 times, how many times run mainBundle method? only once or 100 times?

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful pattern based on GCD which handles this sort of situation nicely:

```
+(NSImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)path{

    static NSString *storedPath;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        storedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"png"];
    });

    // Do whatever you need to do with the default resource path.
}
```

`dispatch_once` does exactly what you are after - it ensures that the initialization code is run only once. It is also thread safe.

Xcode's code completion even helps you use the pattern - if you start typing `dispatch_once` then you'll get the `onceToken` template directly.